# RactiveJS, Stuck at Tutorial 4. Event proxies

Tags: ractivejs

I am following the Tutorials but I am stuck at 4. Event Proxies:

The following doesnt work for me, it just happens nothing:

```
<button on-click='activate'>Activate!</button>
...
ractive.on( 'activate', function ( event ) {
      alert( 'Activating!' );
});
```

Here is a live example:
http://jsbin.com/kupetofawavu/1/

What am I missing, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your buttons *inside* the template and you're good.
Cheers!

Comment: I am stuck again: http://jsbin.com/fusud/3/edit why is the sort event (sort:test) not working but doit:test ?

Comment: Short answer: I'd refrain from using array method names as event names (or as keypath fragments, I guess). No 'sort', 'pop', 'reverse', 'push' etc.

Comment: @daslicht
Longer (untested and probably dangerous) answer: if you're feeling adventurous, change line 230 in your ractive.js build from

`if ( !result[ wildcardKeypath ] ) {`

to

`if ( !result.hasOwnProperty(wildcardKeypath)) {`

While it _seems_ to do the trick, it may cause explosive decompression somewhere else, so... yeah... Exciting!

Comment: does that mean it is a bug ?

Answer (score 1):

Your buttons are outside of the template... move them into the template script tag, and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The buttons need to be in the template. Change

```html
<script id='template' type='text/ractive'>
    <p>Hello, [[name]]!</p>
    <p>[[counter]]</p>   
    <p>[[format(date)]]</p>
</script>
<button id="doit">Count</button>
<button on-click='activate'>Activate!</button>
```

to

```html
<script id='template' type='text/ractive'>
    <p>Hello, [[name]]!</p>
    <p>[[counter]]</p>   
    <p>[[format(date)]]</p>
    <button id="doit">Count</button>
    <button on-click='activate'>Activate!</button>
</script>
```